# ThreeJs - "Cannot read property 'autoUpdate' of undefined"

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use Three.js and I have this error showing in my browser:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import { AxesHelper, PerspectiveCamera, Scene, WebGLRenderer } from 'three'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

const scene = new Scene();
scene.add(new AxesHelper());

const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.z = 2;
camera.position.y = 0.5;
camera.position.x = 0.5;
scene.add(camera);


const renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
tick();

function tick() {
  renderer.render(scene.camera);
  camera.position.x += 0.01;
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
```

I have not a clue on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo: this line...

```
renderer.render(scene.camera);
```

... should actually be written like this:

```
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

... instead ([docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.render)). The error you got is caused by trying to treat `scene.camera` value as `scene` instead, blowing on attempt to access its `autoUpdate` property.